# issue in expandPath in TreePanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I call TreePanel.expandPath(path) immediately after TreePanel.collapseAll(). It is supposed to expand the tree. 
It changes the plus icon of the root node to the minus icon but tree does not expand at all.
How can I fixe this? Does this EXTJS bug?

```
TreePanel.collapseAll();
TreePanel.expandPath(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the collapse/expand animations might be stepping on each other.  Have you tried delaying your expandPath using DelayedTask?

Comment: Yes, I have tried delaying expandPath using DelayTask and it is ok. But there is no other way to fixe this issue?

Comment: This is the only way I've found to handle this kind of stuff. I'm sure there is a better way, but it's a quick and dirty solution.